# In .Net Maui CastContext Fails to initialize

Tags: maui, android-cast-api

Attempting to get Casting to work in .Net Maui on android, and Seems that regardless of what I do. When I Initialize the CastContext inthe OnCreate method of the Android Main Activity, I get the error that it fails to Initialize.  If I dig A little further, it says that the path to the OptionsProvider can not be found, but I'm at a loss.   Seems that regardless of what Namespace I put on the CastOptions Class it is the same error.
Here is the full error message;

> {Java.Lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to initialize CastContext. ---> Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException: MauiApp3.CastOptionsProvider ---> Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException: **Didn't find class "MauiApp3.CastOptionsProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~hN1P4pOlf7nl5c94efSAZA==/com.MauiApp3-**HGXXbCCME0AJRmBkjgKyGg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~hN1P4pOlf7nl5c94efSAZA==/com.MauiApp3-HGXXbCCME0AJRmBkjgKyGg==/lib/arm64, /data/app/~~hN1P4pOlf7nl5c94efSAZA==/com.MauiApp3-HGXXbCCME0AJRmBkjgKyGg==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system/system_ext/lib64]]  --- End of managed Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException stack trace ---java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "MauiApp3.CastOptionsProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~hN1P4pOlf7nl5c94efSAZA==/com.MauiApp3-HGXXbCCME0AJRmBkjgKyGg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~hN1P4pOlf7nl5c94efSAZA==/com.MauiApp3-HGXXbCCME0AJRmBkjgKyGg==/lib/arm64, /data/app/~~hN1P4pOlf7nl5c94efSAZA==/com.MauiApp3-HGXXbCCME0AJRmBkjgKyGg==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system/system_ext/lib64]]    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:259)  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)  at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:536)  at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:467)  at com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.CastContext.zzf(com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast-framework@@21.2.0:7) at com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.CastContext.getSharedInstance(com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast-framework@@21.2.0:15)  at crc64e73e5e987e2fb5cd.MainActivity.n_onCreate(Native Method) at crc64e73e5e987e2fb5cd.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:39)    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8591)   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8570)   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1384)  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4150)   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4325)    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:101)    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2574) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8762)    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:604)    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1067)  --- End of managed Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException stack trace ---java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "MauiApp3.CastOptionsProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~hN1P4pOlf7nl5c94efSAZA==/com.MauiApp3-HGXXbCCME0AJRmBkjgKyGg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~hN1P4pOlf7nl5c94efSAZA==/com.MauiApp3-HGXXbCCME0AJRmBkjgKyGg==/lib/arm64, /data/app/~~hN1P4pOlf7nl5c94efSAZA==/com.MauiApp3-HGXXbCCME0AJRmBkjgKyGg==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system/system_ext/lib64]] at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:259)  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)  at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:536)  at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:467)  at com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.CastContext.zzf(com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast-framework@@21.2.0:7) at com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.CastContext.getSharedInstance(com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast-framework@@21.2.0:15)  at crc64e73e5e987e2fb5cd.MainActivity.n_onCreate(Native Method) at crc64e73e5e987e2fb5cd.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:39)    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8591)   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8570)   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1384)  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4150)   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4325)    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:101)    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2574) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8762)    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:604)    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1067)   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---  --- End of managed Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException stack trace ---java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: MauiApp3.CastOptionsProvider    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)  at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:536)  at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:467)  at com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.CastContext.zzf(com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast-framework@@21.2.0:7) at com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.CastContext.getSharedInstance(com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast-framework@@21.2.0:15)  at crc64e73e5e987e2fb5cd.MainActivity.n_onCreate(Native Method) at crc64e73e5e987e2fb5cd.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:39)    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8591)   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8570)   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1384)  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4150)   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4325)    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:101)    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2574) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8762)    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:604)    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1067)Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "MauiApp3.CastOptionsProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~hN1P4pOlf7nl5c94efSAZA==/com.MauiApp3-HGXXbCCME0AJRmBkjgKyGg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~hN1P4pOlf7nl5c94efSAZA==/com.MauiApp3-HGXXbCCME0AJRmBkjgKyGg==/lib/arm64, /data/app/~~hN1P4pOlf7nl5c94efSAZA==/com.MauiApp3-HGXXbCCME0AJRmBkjgKyGg==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system/system_ext/lib64]]   at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:259)  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)    ... 23 more  --- End of managed Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException stack trace ---java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: MauiApp3.CastOptionsProvider  at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)  at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:536)  at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:467)  at com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.CastContext.zzf(com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast-framework@@21.2.0:7) at com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.CastContext.getSharedInstance(com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast-framework@@21.2.0:15)  at crc64e73e5e987e2fb5cd.MainActivity.n_onCreate(Native Method) at crc64e73e5e987e2fb5cd.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:39)    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8591)   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8570)   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1384)  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4150)   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4325)    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:101)    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2574) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8762)    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:604)    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1067)Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "MauiApp3.CastOptionsProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~hN1P4pOlf7nl5c94efSAZA==/com.MauiApp3-HGXXbCCME0AJRmBkjgKyGg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~hN1P4pOlf7nl5c94efSAZA==/com.MauiApp3-HGXXbCCME0AJRmBkjgKyGg==/lib/arm64, /data/app/~~hN1P4pOlf7nl5c94efSAZA==/com.MauiApp3-HGXXbCCME0AJRmBkjgKyGg==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system/system_ext/lib64]]   at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:259)  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)    ... 23 more   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---   at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment.StaticMethods.CallStaticObjectMethod(JniObjectReference type, JniMethodInfo method, JniArgumentValue* args) in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/obj/Release/net7.0/JniEnvironment.g.cs:line 21452   at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers.JniStaticMethods.InvokeObjectMethod(String encodedMember, JniArgumentValue* parameters) in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/Java.Interop/src/Java.Interop/Java.Interop/JniPeerMembers.JniStaticMethods.cs:line 165   at Android.Gms.Cast.Framework.CastContext.GetSharedInstance(Context context, IExecutor executor) in C:\a_work\1\s\generated\com.google.android.gms.play-services-cast-framework\obj\Release\net6.0-android31.0\generated\src\Android.Gms.Cast.Framework.CastContext.cs:line 413   at MauiApp3.MainActivity.InitializeCastContextAsync(Context context) in C:\Users\josep\source\repos\MauiApp3\MauiApp3\Platforms\Android\MainActivity.cs:line 29   at MauiApp3.MainActivity.OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) in C:\Users\josep\source\repos\MauiApp3\MauiApp3\Platforms\Android\MainActivity.cs:line 20   at Android.App.Activity.n_OnCreate_Landroid_os_Bundle_(IntPtr jnienv, IntPtr native__this, IntPtr native_savedInstanceState) in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/obj/Release/net8.0/android-34/mcw/Android.App.Activity.cs:line 3082   at Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper.Wrap_JniMarshal_PPL_V(_JniMarshal_PPL_V callback, IntPtr jnienv, IntPtr klazz, IntPtr p0) in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/JNINativeWrapper.g.cs:line 125  --- End of managed Java.Lang.IllegalStateException stack trace ---java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to initialize CastContext.    at com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.CastContext.zzf(com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast-framework@@21.2.0:11)    at com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.CastContext.getSharedInstance(com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast-framework@@21.2.0:15)  at crc64e73e5e987e2fb5cd.MainActivity.n_onCreate(Native Method) at crc64e73e5e987e2fb5cd.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:39)    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8591)   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8570)   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1384)  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4150)   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4325)    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:101)    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2574) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8762)    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:604)    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1067)Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: MauiApp3.CastOptionsProvider   at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)  at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:536)  at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:467)  at com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.CastContext.zzf(com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast-framework@@21.2.0:7) ... 19 moreCaused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "MauiApp3.CastOptionsProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~hN1P4pOlf7nl5c94efSAZA==/com.MauiApp3-HGXXbCCME0AJRmBkjgKyGg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~hN1P4pOlf7nl5c94efSAZA==/com.MauiApp3-HGXXbCCME0AJRmBkjgKyGg==/lib/arm64, /data/app/~~hN1P4pOlf7nl5c94efSAZA==/com.MauiApp3-HGXXbCCME0AJRmBkjgKyGg==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system/system_ext/lib64]]    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:259)  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)    ... 23 more  --- End of managed Java.Lang.IllegalStateException stack trace ---java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to initialize CastContext.   at com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.CastContext.zzf(com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast-framework@@21.2.0:11)    at com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.CastContext.getSharedInstance(com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast-framework@@21.2.0:15)  at crc64e73e5e987e2fb5cd.MainActivity.n_onCreate(Native Method) at crc64e73e5e987e2fb5cd.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:39)    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8591)   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8570)   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1384)  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4150)   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4325)    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:101)    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2574) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8762)    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:604)    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1067)Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: MauiApp3.CastOptionsProvider   at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)  at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:536)  at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:467)  at com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.CastContext.zzf(com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast-framework@@21.2.0:7) ... 19 moreCaused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "MauiApp3.CastOptionsProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~hN1P4pOlf7nl5c94efSAZA==/com.MauiApp3-HGXXbCCME0AJRmBkjgKyGg==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~hN1P4pOlf7nl5c94efSAZA==/com.MauiApp3-HGXXbCCME0AJRmBkjgKyGg==/lib/arm64, /data/app/~~hN1P4pOlf7nl5c94efSAZA==/com.MauiApp3-HGXXbCCME0AJRmBkjgKyGg==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system/system_ext/lib64]]    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:259)  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)    ... 23 more}

I have the Path in the Metadata for the android Manifest like here;

```
<application android:allowBackup="true"  android:supportsRtl="true">
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.OPTIONS_PROVIDER_CLASS_NAME" android:value="MauiApp3.CastOptionsProvider" />
```

and I'm Initializing the Context here.

```
   private void InitializeCastContextAsync(Context context)
{
    // Define the executor
    IExecutor executor = AsyncTask.ThreadPoolExecutor;

    // Call the asynchronous method to get the CastContext instance
    Android.Gms.Tasks.Task castContextTask = CastContext.GetSharedInstance(context, executor);

    // Add a continuation task to handle completion
    castContextTask.AddOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener(task =>
    {
        if (task.IsSuccessful)
        {
            // CastContext is initialized
            var castContext = (CastContext)task.Result;
            // Do something with castContext...
        }
        else
        {
            // Handle initialization failure
            Exception exception = task.Exception;
            // Log or display error...
        }
    }));

}
```

Lastly here is the CastOptionsProvider.

```
using Android.Content;
using Android.Gms.Cast.Framework;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;



namespace com.companyname.mauiapp3   <-- I keep changing this to try to see if that Java error ever changes.
{
    public class CastOptionsProvider : Java.Lang.Object, IOptionsProvider
    {
        public CastOptions GetCastOptions(Context appContext)
        {
            var options = new CastOptions.Builder()
                .SetReceiverApplicationId("7AA05E47")
                .Build();

            return options;
        }

        //public IPackageChannel GetCastChannel(string channelId)
        //{
        //    return null;
        //}

        public IList<SessionProvider> GetAdditionalSessionProviders(Context appContext)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

I made the changes as mentioned to match the Package name and its the same error;

> {Java.Lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to initialize CastContext. ---> Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.companyname.mauiapp3.CastOptionsProvider ---> Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.companyname.mauiapp3.CastOptionsProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~e4NAlnd0xGIU7m0aJHvm4Q==/com.companyname.mauiapp3-RJaoXOgIxunzik9DWGGSgA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~e4NAlnd0xGIU7m0aJHvm4Q==/com.companyname.mauiapp3-RJaoXOgIxunzik9DWGGSgA==/lib/arm64, /data/app/~~e4NAlnd0xGIU7m0aJHvm4Q==/com.companyname.mauiapp3-RJaoXOgIxunzik9DWGGSgA==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system/system_ext/lib64]]  --- End of managed Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException stack trace ---java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.companyname.mauiapp3.CastOptionsProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~e4NAlnd0xGIU7m0aJHvm4Q==/com.companyname.mauiapp3-RJaoXOgIxunzik9DWGGSgA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~e4NAlnd0xGIU7m0aJHvm4Q==/com.companyname.mauiapp3-RJaoXOgIxunzik9DWGGSgA==/lib/arm64, /data/app/~~e4NAlnd0xGIU7m0aJHvm4Q==/com.companyname.mauiapp3-RJaoXOgIxunzik9DWGGSgA==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system/system_ext/lib64]]    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:259)  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)    at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)  at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:536)

Adding the  Oncomplete listner method

```
// Helper class to handle task completion
public class OnCompleteListener : Java.Lang.Object, IOnCompleteListener
{
    private readonly Action<Android.Gms.Tasks.Task> _onComplete;

    public OnCompleteListener(Action<Android.Gms.Tasks.Task> onComplete)
    {
        _onComplete = onComplete;
    }

    public void OnComplete(Android.Gms.Tasks.Task task)
    {
        _onComplete?.Invoke(task);
    }
}
```

Uploading Project file..

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFrameworks>net8.0-android;net8.0-ios;net8.0-maccatalyst</TargetFrameworks>
        <TargetFrameworks Condition="$([MSBuild]::IsOSPlatform('windows'))">$(TargetFrameworks);net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFrameworks>
        <!-- Uncomment to also build the tizen app. You will need to install tizen by following this: https://github.com/Samsung/Tizen.NET -->
        <!-- <TargetFrameworks>$(TargetFrameworks);net8.0-tizen</TargetFrameworks> -->

        <!-- Note for MacCatalyst:
        The default runtime is maccatalyst-x64, except in Release config, in which case the default is maccatalyst-x64;maccatalyst-arm64.
        When specifying both architectures, use the plural <RuntimeIdentifiers> instead of the singular <RuntimeIdentifier>.
        The Mac App Store will NOT accept apps with ONLY maccatalyst-arm64 indicated;
        either BOTH runtimes must be indicated or ONLY macatalyst-x64. -->
        <!-- For example: <RuntimeIdentifiers>maccatalyst-x64;maccatalyst-arm64</RuntimeIdentifiers> -->

        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <RootNamespace>MauiApp3</RootNamespace>
        <UseMaui>true</UseMaui>
        <SingleProject>true</SingleProject>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>

        <!-- Display name -->
        <ApplicationTitle>MauiApp3</ApplicationTitle>

        <!-- App Identifier -->
        <ApplicationId>com.companyname.mauiapp3</ApplicationId>

        <!-- Versions -->
        <ApplicationDisplayVersion>1.0</ApplicationDisplayVersion>
        <ApplicationVersion>1</ApplicationVersion>

        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'ios'">11.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'maccatalyst'">13.1</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'android'">21.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'windows'">10.0.17763.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <TargetPlatformMinVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'windows'">10.0.17763.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'tizen'">6.5</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <!-- App Icon -->
        <MauiIcon Include="Resources\AppIcon\appicon.svg" ForegroundFile="Resources\AppIcon\appiconfg.svg" Color="#512BD4" />

        <!-- Splash Screen -->
        <MauiSplashScreen Include="Resources\Splash\splash.svg" Color="#512BD4" BaseSize="128,128" />

        <!-- Images -->
        <MauiImage Include="Resources\Images\*" />
        <MauiImage Update="Resources\Images\dotnet_bot.png" Resize="True" BaseSize="300,185" />

        <!-- Custom Fonts -->
        <MauiFont Include="Resources\Fonts\*" />

        <!-- Raw Assets (also remove the "Resources\Raw" prefix) -->
        <MauiAsset Include="Resources\Raw\**" LogicalName="%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Controls" Version="8.0.6" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility" Version="8.0.6" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="8.0.0" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'net8.0-android'">
      <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Cast">
        <Version>121.2.0</Version>
      </PackageReference>
      <PackageReference Include="Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Cast.Framework">
        <Version>121.2.0</Version>
      </PackageReference>
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Did you use .net 6.0 and Xamarin.GoolgePlayService.Cast.Framework 121.2.0?

Comment: @Liyun Zhang - MSFT  I added the Project file.  I'm running .net 8 with the Nuget package you mentioned.  I've tried to use the latest of the Nuget packages. but that has other errors and won't even build.     I' did manage to get casting using the GoogleCast Package but it doesn't look like it supports custom web receivers, which is a requiremet for this.

Comment: Yes, I tested the nuget package in the .net 7/8. Both of them couldn't build. So how did you build your project and meet the error at runtime?

Comment: @Liyun Zhang - MSFT     Yup, the latest version of the nuget pkg will crash during build every time, but if you roll it back, I managed to get this far.  I'm still not 100% sure if I will need both the GPS.Framework and GPS.Cast pkgs yet but I'm taking small steps to try to get to a stable position.  Also, My target is not a default Reciever, I'm going to use a custom reciever,    Here is the MauiApp3 GitHub Repo. https://github.com/Jricklefs/MauiApp3/tree/master/MauiApp3

Comment: @Liyun Zhang - MSFT posted the code in a gibhub.

Comment: Please check the update answer and I have fixed this error.

Comment: @ Liyun Zhang - MSFT   Thank you for the assistance.  I've been banging head for a week.      Do you happen to have a good guide to implement the CastingButton?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the error message:

> Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException: MauiApp3.CastOptionsProvider  ---> Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "MauiApp3.CastOptionsProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~hN1P4pOlf7nl5c94efSAZA==/com.MauiApp3-HGXXbCCME0AJRmBkjgKyGg==/base.apk"]

If you used `<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.OPTIONS_PROVIDER_CLASS_NAME" android:value="MauiApp3.CastOptionsProvider" />` directly, the class can't be found.

You can register it by the `Android.Runtime.Register` at first. Such as:

```
[Register("MauiApp3/CastOptionsProvider")]
public class CastOptionsProvider : Java.Lang.Object, IOptionsProvider
```

And then declare it in the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/appicon" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/appicon_round" android:supportsRtl="true">
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.cast.framework.OPTIONS_PROVIDER_CLASS_NAME" 
    android:value="MauiApp3.CastOptionsProvider" />
</application>
```

Comment: I made the change and no luck.

Comment: Here is the latest error message after chaning the android:value to  match the package name. ;

Comment: Can you show the code about OnCompleteListener? I can't use your code if miss it. @JoeRicklefs

Comment: In addition, please make the CastOptionsProvider in the NameSpace MauiApp3. And the com.companyname.mauiapp3 is my project's package name. You can check yours in the csproj file. @JoeRicklefs

Comment: You can also try to use the CastOptionsProvider's namespace. Such as: `android:value="YourClassNameSpace.CastOptionsProvider"`. @JoeRicklefs

Comment: I added the OnCOmpleteListener.   The namespace in the Meta tags I originally thad matched to the namespace of the CastOptionsProviderClass as your last suggestion, but the error message does not change.